# What machine learning i can use for classifing EMG data from MyoArm Band?

Tags: python, classification

I'm working on a project which i receive some EMG data from Myo Arm Band
I need to clasify them, what machine learning algorithm can be good for this?

Comment: Please be specific when asking your questions. S.O. is not a discussion forum, but best used to answer specific code related problems. Also, please spell out all abbreviations (EMG) for better understanding.

Answer (score -2):

you can use svm. kernels can be varied depending on number of movements to classify and it has high accuracy. i would recommend you to read some research paper related to this.